# How do I get colors even while just listing normally in zsh

Tags: debian, zsh

See the below listing -

```
/home/shirish/games/gtimelog> ls

.   CONTRIBUTORS.rst .gitattributes  gtimelog.appdata.xml help 
org.gtimelog.gschema.xml scripts tox.ini COPYING gitignore gtimelog.desktop locale  other-requirements.txt setup.cfg .travis.yml appveyor.yml .coveragerc gschemas.compiled gtimelog.desktop.in Makefile    po setup.py benchmark.py docs gtimelog gtimelogrc.5 MANIFEST.in README.rst src CONTRIBUTING.rst .git gtimelog.1 gtimelog.rst NEWS.rst runtests TODO.rst
```

In above, I don't see any colors differentiating between files and directories.

If however, I do proper long listing using `$ls -la` I get the colors which tell me which are directories and which are files  . Is there a way so even while casual doing a listing the colors for directories is there ?

Comment: Do the `ls -la` and then tell us what doesn't work or that you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @JuliePelletier did, sorry was about to sleep when I gave the query/question hence didn't frame it properly. Guy did it good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just mean to add  a mixture of colours, many gnu programs accept the flag `--colour=auto` to include highlighting etc.

This can then be automatically included in your commands by running

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

This is usually already done for Bash in Debian, but maybe not in ZSh.